# How do I authenticate, using Nim's httpclient module to retrieve HTML?

Tags: authentication, https, nim-lang

I'm a beginner and I want to write a Nim-application that processes some data from an internal website.
Basic authentication (username, password) is required to access this site.

A working Python solution is:

```
response = requests.get('https://internal:PORT/page',
                        auth=('user', 'passwd'),
                        verify=False) # this is vital
```

Based on the nim doc regarding httpclient and the modules source code, where it is stated that one could use a proxy as an argument for any of the functions, I've been trying something along these lines:

```
var 
  client = newHttpClient()
  prox = newProxy("https://internal:PORT/page", "user:passwd")

let response = client.getContent(prox) # Error: type mismatch
```

The solution is probably very obvious but I'm out of ideas on 
how to authenticate.

If anybody could help, that'd be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basic auth is just an "Authorization" header with value "Basic " + base64(username + ":" + password). Equivalent in nim:

```
import httpclient, base64
var
    client = newHttpClient()
var username = ...
var password = ...
client.headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " & base64.encode(username & ":" & password)
# ... send request with the client
```

Comment: Worked like a charme.
I'm going to do some more research on headers and the like to improve as a developer.
Thanks a lot!